# How do I split an WooCommerce order programmatically?

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I sell packages online in my store. When a customer orders 2 packages (1 package consists of 4 products), I want to create 2 orders with 1 package, instead of 1 order with 2 packages.

Example:
I have a package (ID: 212), which can consist of up to 4 bundled products (all ID: 730). The problem right now: When I try to split the order, only the product with ID 212 is put into a new order. The 4 products, which belong to ID 212 still stay in the same order.

Following a screenshot, which makes the hierarchy more clear:

[image]

What happens, when I try the solution from @Shir Gans:

[image]

The package is put into a new order, but the products, which should also be in the new order are still in the old order.

What is the easiest way to do this, and which hook do I have to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook to `woocommerce_payment_complete` which accepts `$order_id`, then you can loop through the items and decide if to create another order. Then you can split the items into a new order. here is an (untested) example:

```
define('PACKAGE_PRODUCT_ID', 1010);

    add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_splitter', 100, 1);
    function order_splitter($order_id){
        $completed_order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $item_splitted = false;

        $address = array(
            'first_name' => $completed_order->get_billing_first_name(),
            'last_name'  => $completed_order->get_billing_last_name(),
            'company'    => '',
            'email'      => $completed_order->get_billing_email(),
            'phone'      => $completed_order->get_billing_phone(),
            'address_1'  => $completed_order->get_billing_address_1(),
            'address_2'  => $completed_order->get_billing_address_2(),
            'city'       => $completed_order->get_billing_city(),
            'state'      => $completed_order->get_billing_state(),
            'postcode'   => $completed_order->get_billing_postcode(),
            'country'    => $completed_order->get_billing_country()
        );

        foreach($completed_order->get_items() as $item){

                if (!$item_splitted && $item->get_product_id() === PACKAGE_PRODUCT_ID) {

                    //create new order
                    $new_order_args = array(
                        'customer_id' => $completed_order->get_customer_id(),
                        'status' => 'wc-pending',
                    );
                    $new_order = wc_create_order($new_order_args);
                    $product_to_add = wc_get_product(PACKAGE_PRODUCT_ID);
                    $new_order->add_product($product_to_add, 1, array());
                    $new_order->set_address($address, 'billing');
                    $new_order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
                    $new_order->update_status('wc-processing');
                    $new_order->add_order_note('This order created automatically');
                    $new_order->save();
                    $completed_order->remove_item($item->get_id());
                    $item_splitted = true;
                } else  if ($item_splitted && $item['product_id'] === PACKAGE_PRODUCT_ID){
                    # This will ensure every 2 products are splitted (skipping the 2nd one)
                    $item_splitted = false;
                    continue;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It kind of worked: Except: The item, which I put in the other order is still in the original order. And also it doesn't work for bundled products. I will update my question. But thank you!

Comment: I think it's a point where you should consider to continue yourself. Stackoverflow community can give you a good idea of how to continue, but less likely you will get a full working solution. Sounds you need to play with it a bit to have exactly what you need